# Match Sketch(Drawing) face photo to digital color photo

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, feature-extraction

I'm going to match the sketch face (drawing photo) in to the color photo. so for the research i want to find out what are the challenges that matching sketch drawing in to color faces. for now i have find out that

1. resolution pixel difference
2. texture difference
3. distance difference
4. and color (not much effect)

I want to know (in technical terms) what are other challenges and what are available `OPEN CV` and `JAVA CV` method and algorithms to overcome that challenges?

Here is some example of the sketches and the photos that are known to match them:

[image: data]

Comment: you might want to give more detail about your data, or else it's not really an answerable question. i.e. does your data consist of all front-facing photos with the face in-frame, or are they completly unstructured, or something inbetween? What kind of sketches are these? stick figures? Police-blotters? Cubist drawings?

Comment: thanx for reply            they are all front faceing photos with same background (like id card photo). there arent anything between. all sketches are human faces not stick figures like this  (http://mmlab.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/archive/facesketch_files/image004.jpg)

Comment: Are any of these answers helpful? The bounty ends tomorrow and if you don't select a right answer I'm going with the one with the most votes (which is also a really good answer, as are all of these (you SO people make me so proud to be a part of this :)

Answer (score 4):

This problem is called multi-modal face recognition. There has been a lot of interest in comparing a high quality mugshot (modality 1) to low quality surveillance images (modality 2), another is frontal images to profiles, or pictures to sketches like the OP is interested in. Partial Least Squares (PLS) and Tied Factor Analysis (TFA) have been used for this purpose.

A key difficulty is computing two linear projections from the image in modality 1 (and modality 2) to a space where two points being close means that the individual is the same. This is the key technical step. Here are some papers on this approach:

1. Abhishek Sharma, David W Jacobs :  [Bypassing Synthesis: PLS for
   Face Recognition with Pose, Low-Resolution and Sketch](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~djacobs/pubs_files/PLSCVPR.pdf). CVPR
   2011.
2. S.J.D. Prince, J.H. Elder, J. Warrell, F.M. Felisberti, [Tied Factor
   Analysis for Face Recognition across Large Pose Differences](http://elderlab.yorku.ca/~elder/publications/journals/PrincePAMI08.pdf), IEEE
   Patt. Anal. Mach. Intell, 30(6), 970-984, 2008. Elder is a specialist in this area and has [a variety of papers on the topic](http://elderlab.yorku.ca/~elder/?page=pub&lb=lbNone).
3. B. Klare, Z. Li and A. K. Jain, [Matching forensic sketches to
   mugshot photos](http://cs.iupui.edu/~tuceryan/pdf-repository/Klare2011.pdf), IEEE Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, 29
   Sept. 2010.

As you can understand this is an active research area/problem. In terms using OpenCV to overcome the difficulties, let me give you an analogy: you need to build build a house (match sketches to photos) and you're asking how will having a Stanley hammer (OpenCV) will help. Sure, it will probably help. But you'll also need a lot of other resources: wood, time/money, pipes, cable, etc.

Comment: Yup, as I said below, J.H. Elder has been active in related areas for quite a while. There may be more of his work that's relevant. See his selected bibliography here: http://elderlab.yorku.ca/~elder/?page=pub&lb=lbNone

Comment: OpenCV = Stanley hammer. Very nice analogy.

Answer (score 2):

I think that James Elder's old work on the completeness of the edge map (using reconstruction by solving the Laplace equation) is quite relevant here. See the results at the end of this paper: http://elderlab.yorku.ca/~elder/publications/journals/ElderIJCV99.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You could give Eigenfaces a try, though i never tested them with sketches i think they could a least be a good starting point for your research.

See Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface and the Tutorial for OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html (including not only Eigenfaces!)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can be used for feature extraction and machine learning required for this task. I guess you can start with the papers in the answers above, start with some basic features and prototype a classifier with OpenCV.

I guess you might also want to detect and match feature points on the faces. If you use this approach, you will have to do the feature point detectors on your own (training the Viola-Jones detector in OpenCV with your own data is an option).